# Monoid actions - is this action inelegant?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions, natural-numbers, monoid

I’m recently delving into abstract algebra, and I’ve attempted to devise a monoid action on the natural numbers. I think I must be missing something here—is there a better way to represent these same operations as an algebra?

I’ve defined a transformation monoid of $\mathbb{N}$ such that the elements are the nth-prime function $p$, the “curried” multiply-by-$k$ function for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (which includes the identity as $k=1$), and all compositions of these. So the basis is $(n \mapsto p_n, n \mapsto n, n \mapsto 2n, n \mapsto 3n, \ldots)$. The monoid operation is function composition.

Including each separate multiply-by-$k$ function seems like a mistake, or at least inelegant—especially if I let the natural numbers also be a multiplicative monoid $(\mathbb{N}, \times)$. It seems like a redundancy.

Is there a better way to represent this? What am I missing?

Comment: I feel like the action *itself* is inelegant (i.e. arbitrary and contrived), not the *description* of the action.

Comment: Well, that was the question in the title: whether the *action* was inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are defining a submonoid $T$ of the monoid $T_{\Bbb N}$ of all transformations on $\Bbb N$. Your monoid $T$ is generated by the transformation $\pi: n \to p_n$ and by the transformations $\rho_k: n \to kn$, for all $k > 0$. It turns out that the set $M = \{\rho_k \mid k > 0\}$ is closed under composition and hence forms a submonoid of $T_{\Bbb N}$, namely the monoid of all non-zero translations of $(\Bbb N, \times)$. Note that $M$ is generated by the set $P = \{\rho_p \mid \text{$p$ is prime}\}$ and is actually the free commutative monoid of base $P$. I guess that is what you mean when you talk about the *redundancy* of $M$.

Describing $T$ is more complicated, since it involves the powers of $\pi$. But as the submonoid $N$ of $T$ generated by $\pi$ is free and isomorphic to $({\Bbb N}, 0, +)$, I would guess that $T$ is isomorphic to the free product of $N$ and $M$.